# Using width with orientation

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some div classes:

```
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-reply- 
to-ad/31/3-books/"><div class="email"><span><center><span class="fa 
fa-envelope"></span></center></span></div></a><a href="tel:<br/>. 
<label>Phone:</label> XXXX. XXXX XXXX"><div class="phone"><span>. 
<center><span class="fas fa-phone"</span></center></span></div></a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<br/><label>Location:</label> 
London, London, 
UK&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false""><div 
class="location"><span><center><span class="fas fa-map-marker-alt". 
</span></center></span></div></a>
```

One,`.email` i can't seem to alter the width in `orientation:landscape`

Tried css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)and (orientation: landscape){.email {padding:0px; position: unset; float:unset; width: unset;background-color:unset; margin:unset; height:unset; display:unset;}}
```

and

```
@media (max-width: 768px)and (orientation: landscape){.awpcp-subtitle >.email {width: 10px !important; display:block;}}
```

Page for mobile landscapes view :https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/31/3-books/london/uk/london/business-advert/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And nice punt, but didn't work...

Comment: What should be auto sorry?`.awpcp-subtitle {?}`?

Comment: I'm using WordPress so as i understand my php generates my html and`awpcp-subtitle` is the div class above. I tried to use it as a specificity selector.... Tried setting width to auto `.email {width: auto;} ` too - nothing.

Comment: Tried using % too-nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your help though...

Comment: Ok. One thing I've noticed os that I've got `background-color: unset`and it hasn't unset it. Do you think the clue might lie there somewhere? I mean what could be stopping it from unsetting the color? Unless `important` or if there's a totally different selector? Perhaps even `a`? `. email a{foo}`

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: The last thing I can suggest is trying ‘@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){ *{background-colour: black;}}’ to rule any issues loading the css or being able to use media queries. If that works, try swapping * {} with .email {}. If your email turns black, you know the issue is either with the selector or the rule.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try. Just deleted the first part of my css with all the unset stuff and now the `fafa` is responding but not the background colour. `width: 50px;` now sends the` fafa` to the left...nothing else...

Comment: Ok so `*` worked amd entire sections of my site turned black. What I've just tried then, is to turn the background colour of the div class black, like so`@media (max-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {.email {background-color: black; width: 50px;}}`. The button color is now 30% black and 70% green. I've noticed this overlaying with another button on a separate page too...

Comment: So is there a css property which is fixing my colours? Or an overlay property I'm not aware of?

Comment: I've got a button here which is kinda holographic. https://adsler.co.uk/job/holland-and-barratt-london-4-store-colleague/

Comment: It happened because i tried to change the color and that's what came out.....:-) it just layed the colours on top of each other and that's what came out `apply for job`

Comment: The HTML code is invalid and has multiple syntax issues. If you can fix that up, it will be easier to understand the specific issue. In the meantime, there are some working examples with orientation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Managing_screen_orientation

Comment: @OXiGEN ok cool. Thanks for the tip...

Comment: @Lewis odd though huh?